# How to make svg text like inline-block

Tags: html, css, svg

Trying to create chart legend.

```
<svg>
    <g class="legend">
        <g>
            <rect fill="blue" width="1em" height="1em" />
            <text>Bosnia and Herzegovina</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect fill="red" width="1em" height="1em" />
            <text>Democratic Republic of the Congo</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Obviously, each item starts at (0, 0) on top of previous one. Is there a way to make them behave more like inline-block elements?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nngptbtn/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with 'pure' SVG. SVG doesn't have automatic text layout features like HTML.  It expects you to position each piece of text yourself.

However, if you want to have a paragraph of text, and as long as your SVG is only going to be used in a browser, you can embed HTML inside your SVG using the `<foreignObject>` element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject