# How to get generated text to go on a new line after a number of characters

Tags: jquery, svg

So I have a photo frame designer you can find [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2). It is built using SVG. On it it allows the user to input their own text which displays on the photo frame. After 18 characters the text is too long to display on just one line. So how can I get it to move down a line when this 18 characters is exceeded?

Here is some code. The full code is on the website if needed.

```
<text class="text" transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 624.6 550.5599)" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="41.6368">Your words here</text>

$('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('.text').html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make svg text like inline-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815153/how-to-make-svg-text-like-inline-block)

Comment: I disagree. Yes I want to make it appear on a new line using say the <br> tag, but I want to know how to insert this after the 18th character.

Comment: The answer I gave to the linked question applies here as well.  SVG itself has no automatic text layout capability.  It expects you to position individual pieces of text yourself.  Just as you position shapes like rectangles or circles.

Comment: Right. But I'm after the piece of code which say would be jQuery to tell when there have been n number of characters and then add the html.

Comment: You don't need any code like that.  If you use a `<foreignObject>`, the HTML engine will do the layout for you.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic SVG only has simple layout of a single line of text.  It cannot layout blocks of text like HTML can.

However it does have the ability to embed foreign objects.  When using SVG in the browser environment, you can use this feature to embed blocks of HTML.  To embed HTML, use the `<foreignObject>` element.

```
<foreignObject x="78" y="460" width="1100" height="200"
               style="color:white;font-size:80;text-align:center">
   <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <p>A caption with automatic wrapping courtesy of HTML</p>
   </body>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7frnddqj/1/)

Comment: Wait how did you get it to wrap?

Comment: Ahh so it's automatic. But now my font looks jagged and it's the wrong size.

Comment: Did you read my answer?  I am using SVG's `<foreignObject>` element to embed some HTML within the SVG.  The browser's HTML engine is being used to render that particular element.  Hence we get all the layout capabilities of HTML, including text wrap.

Comment: Yes I did. I understand how the tag works. But the problem is a difference in font and size and interaction with the jQuery. I may be being ridiculous, I think I'm just feeling a bit overwhelmed by my project.

Comment: I'm not sure what the behaviour of all browsers are with respect to the inheritance of styles into SVG and then into a foreignObject.  You may have to add explicit rules to your CSS for the contents of the foreignObject.  Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/7frnddqj/2/